# Is there a safe way for a struct to store a slice of a vector that will be modified outside the struct?

Tags: rust, slice, lifetime, unsafe, ownership

I'm implementing code that handles a vector of length `k * n` and creates
`k` points of length `n` that reference a slice of the original vector:

```rust
struct Point<'a> {
    values: &'a [f32],
}

impl<'a> Point<'a> {
    pub fn new(values: &'a [f32]) -> Self {
        Point { values }
    }

    pub fn dist_euclidian(&self, point: &Point) -> Result<f32, &str> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

When I try to test it:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_euclidian_distance() {
    let mut v1 = vec![7.0, 11.0];
    let mut v2 = vec![40.0, -27.0];
    let p1: Point = Point::new(&v1[..]);
    let p2: Point = Point::new(&v2[..]);

    assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 50.32).abs() <= 0.01);

    v1[0] = 0.0;
    v1[1] = -4.0;
    v2[0] = 8.0;
    v2[1] = 100.0;

    assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 104.3072).abs() <= 0.01);
}
```

I get the following error(s):

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/k_means/point.rs:56:9
   |
51 |         let p1: Point = Point::new(&v1[..]);
   |                                     -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
56 |         v1[0] = 0.0;
   |         ^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
61 |         assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 104.3072).abs() <= 0.01);
   |                  -- immutable borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v1` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/k_means/point.rs:57:9
   |
51 |         let p1: Point = Point::new(&v1[..]);
   |                                     -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
57 |         v1[1] = -4.0;
   |         ^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
61 |         assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 104.3072).abs() <= 0.01);
   |                  -- immutable borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v2` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/k_means/point.rs:58:9
   |
52 |         let p2: Point = Point::new(&v2[..]);
   |                                     -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
58 |         v2[0] = 8.0;
   |         ^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
61 |         assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 104.3072).abs() <= 0.01);
   |                                    --- immutable borrow later used here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v2` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/k_means/point.rs:59:9
   |
52 |         let p2: Point = Point::new(&v2[..]);
   |                                     -- immutable borrow occurs here
...
59 |         v2[1] = 100.0;
   |         ^^ mutable borrow occurs here
60 | 
61 |         assert!((p1.dist_euclidian(&p2).unwrap() - 104.3072).abs() <= 0.01);
   |                                    --- immutable borrow later used here
```

Is there a safe way of doing what I intend to do?

Comment: I encourage you to look at some of the [**250+** questions about the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq+cannot+borrow+as+mutable+because+it+is+also+borrowed+as).

Answer (score 3):

It's unfortunate that Rust's references have a name similar to storing "by reference" in other languages, but that's not what they are. Rust's references are for *temporary* views into data, when you want to limit usage of that data to a certain scope and preventing it from being used outside that scope. That is the opposite of what you need here.

If you want to keep something, *don't* use temporary references for it. Use owned values instead, which can be stored permanently and moved around. 99% of the time it's a mistake to put a reference inside a struct.

Instead of trying to hold on to a temporarily borrowed slice `&'a [f32]`, store an owned `Vec<f32>` or an owned slice `Box<[f32]>`.

If you expect points to have two dimensions, it'd be more efficient to use fields, 2-element array or a tuple `(f32, f32)`. If you want a small, but variable number of dimensions, it's more efficient to use [`ArrayVec<[f32; 4]>`](https://lib.rs/arrayvec).